# Java - assinging a replaced string , or printing it

Tags: java, printing, heap-memory

Is there a difference between this:

```
String str1 = "abcabc";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("a", "");
System.out.print(str2);
```

And

```
String str1 = "abcabc";
System.out.print(str1.replaceAll("a", ""));
```

In terms of memory used, or in other words, will the print method create memory in the heap for the new string?

Comment: No, that happens when you call `replaceAll()`.

Comment: No difference   between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str1.replaceAll("a", "")
```

returns a new `String` instance. So "Yes", it does create it on the heap, & "Yes" they are the same. *(memory speaking)*